# Regex to escape double quotes inside double quotes with preg_replace

Tags: php

I've been trying to escape all double quotes inside double quotes (yeah, crazy) all day long and i'm finally giving up. I have this kind of data:

```
{ "test": "testing with "data" like this", "subject": "trying the "special" chars" }
```

I've been trying to preg_replace every `"` with `\"` inside something like this `/"(.*)+, "/` which means everything inside double quotes, followed by a comma and space.

I need a way to turn this:

```
{ "test": "testing with "data" like this", "subject": "trying the "special" chars" }
```

Into this:

```
{ "test": "testing with \"data\" like this", "subject": "trying the \"special\" chars" }
```

Using preg_replace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at your regex I would suggest reading up on [regex greediness.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) If you are selecting everything between quotes to the first comma, you will run into problems. The first thing returned would be `test": "testing with "data" like this` so then if you replaced all `"` with `\"` you would have `test\": \"testing with \"data\" like this` which obviously is not what you want. I would recommend using something like this:

```
/"((?:.|\n)*?)"\s*[:,}]\s*/
```

**Explanation**

- **`"((?:.|\n)*?)"`** - captures any character between two quotations; the minimum amount while still having the pattern be true
- **`\s*`** - matches 0 or more whitespace characters
- **`[:,}]`** - match either a colon, comma, or right bracket character
- **`\s*`** - matches 0 or more whitespace characters

Using this regex and your data, the first thing returned is `test`. The next thing returned would be `testing with "data" like this` so after replacing you would have `testing with \"data\" like this`.

---

**UPDATE**

```
$test = '{ "test": "testing with "data" like this", "subject": "trying the "special" chars" }';
$pattern = '/"((?:.|\n)*?)"\s*[:,}]\s*/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $test, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    $answers[] = str_replace('"','\\"',$match);
}
print_r($answers);
// Outputs
// Array ( [0] => test [1] => testing with \"data\" like this [2] => subject [3] => trying the \"special\" chars )
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I think using `preg_match_all` and then `str_replace` is a better way to solve your problem because that regex is much more stable. But if you insist on using `preg_replace` then you can use this code:

```
$string = '{ "test": "testing with "data" like this", "subject": "trying the "special" chars" }';
$pattern = '/(?<!:|: )"(?=[^"]*?"(( [^:])|([,}])))/';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, '\\"', $string);
print_r($string);
//Outputs
//{ "test": "testing with \"data\" like this", "subject": "trying the \"special\" chars" }
```

**Explanation**

- **`(?<!`** - starts a negative lookbehind
- **`:|: )`** - matches a colon or a colon with a space and ends the lookbehind
- **`"`** - matches a quotation
- **`(?=`** - starts a positive lookahead
- **`[^"]*?`** - match anything except a quotation; the minimum amount while still having the pattern be true
- **`"(( [^:])|([,}]))`** - matches a quotation followed by a space and anything but a colon OR it matches a quotation followed by either a comma or right bracket
- **`)`** - ends the lookahead

You can [read more about regex lookaheads here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241152/explanation-of-lookaheads-in-this-regular-expression) I think that this regex is messy although technically it works. I was going to keep playing with it to make it better but I'm tired so I'm going to bed now. This regex allows your data to be more loosely typed. Both of these work, and any combination of them:

```
{ "test" : "testing with "data" like this" , "subject" : "trying the "special" chars" }
{"test":"testing with "data" like this","subject":"trying the "special" chars"}
```

Comment: Escape characters like \n and \t can be present between quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to select only the quotes between double quotes ending with either , or } ? Like this: /: "(["]*)" [,}]/

Comment: Still, this doesn't help me isolating the double quotes inside the other double-quotes. I want to isolate them so i can replace with \"

Comment: @vinnylinux - I updated my post so you can see how it will help with your problem. And the regex now accepts any character.

Comment: Amazing, detailed, didactic answer... THANKS!

Comment: The preg_replace version of the regex fails on some circunstances. For example, if the first case has quotes but the second not: {"test":"testing with "data" like this","subject":"trying the not so special chars"}

Comment: The only thing stopping me from using the preg_match_all version is the slowness.

Comment: @vinnylinux - Ok I added a negative lookbehind which should fix your problem.

Comment: Good one! However, this does not work correctly when the quote may not be followed by a space, but by a period. To cover this case, you need to change a few things.
Instead of checking `space` like "(( [^:])|([,}])) you need use "(([ \.][^:])|([,}]))  I replaced space by [ \.]