# Replace quotes after double quotes in string

Tags: php, regex

I have following string:

```
<something=""Some" random string"  somethingelse="Another "random" string">
```

I need to change it to this

```
<something="&quot;Some&quot; random string"  somethingelse="Another &quot;random&quot; string">
```

Basically leaving the 'outer' quotes and changing the quotes inside them to `&quot;`

I thought some regex might be used to do this, but I'm not sure what the logic should be. Any idea?

Comment: so you haven't tried anything yourseld, yet?

Comment: you should [see the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290882/regex-to-escape-double-quotes-inside-double-quotes-with-preg-replace)

Comment: just put \" where you want your quote or use single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo '<something='.chr(34).'Some'.chr(34).' random string"  somethingelse="Another "random" string">';
```

for example:

you can try this: `echo chr(34).'Some'.chr(34).' random string';`

```
"Some" random string
```

[image: Ascii Table for Quotes and different elements]

Comment: What question are you answering?