# How to convert JSON string (with double quotes in its values) to python dictionary

Tags: python, json, string

I have some JSON files like this:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "ADIZERO ADIOS PRO 2 Löparskor",
    "@id": "adidas-adizero-adios-pro-2-loparskor",
    "color": "Lila",
    "description": "Example text "Best Comfort" an other example text.",
    "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "adidas"
    },
    "audience": {
    "@type": "Audience",
    "name": "Herr, Dam"
    }        
}
```

I know it is not a valid JSON file since in the description field there is `" "` but how can I manipulate this string with python and use `json.loads()`

I'm thinking about some regular expressions to remove these inner double quotes, Is that possible?

BTW: It's not possible to manipulate the source JSON files.

Comment: fix the problem at the source, where this is created

Comment: I can't manipulate the source file @buran

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290882/regex-to-escape-double-quotes-inside-double-quotes-with-preg-replace see if that can help you

Answer (score 0):

## The Right Answer -- do it right, GIGO, etc.

Definitely fix the problem at the source. Or else you're just plugging holes in a leaking dam. Who knows what other special characters might appear in the text, in the future if the program receives new input?

## The Pragmatic Answer -- you asked for it

Here's an example Python script that takes the "bad JSON" on stdin and produces (hopefully) valid JSON output on stdout:

```py
import sys
import re

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        # Replace content where the property value has invalid
        # double quotes that were supposed to be part of the string
        # with properly quoted double quotes.
        line = re.sub(r'(: ")(.*)(",)$', replacer, line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

def replacer(match):
    before = match.group(1)
    string_to_fix = match.group(2)
    after = match.group(3)
    return before + escape_quotes(string_to_fix) + after

def replacer2(match):
    return match.group(1) + match.group(2).upper() + match.group(3)

def escape_quotes(s):
    return s.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"')

main()
```